# why Base64 is used in OutputType Interface?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, base64

I want to know that why base64 is used with outputtype interface of selenium.
I used to take the screenshot as File type,Base64 type,Bytes[] type but not understand the concept of base64?

Answer (score 0):

As you try to take screenshots through [TakesScreenshot](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) Interface you can save the output file in either of the following formats :

- **FILE** : Obtain the screenshot into a temporary file that will be deleted once the JVM exits.

  ```
  File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
  ```
- **BASE64** : Obtain the screenshot as base64 data.

  ```
  String screenshotBase64 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
  ```
- **BYTES** : Obtain the screenshot as raw bytes.

  ```
  byte[] screenshotByte = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
  ```

### Why Base64 Encoding

When you intend to send across binary data through a network, you can't send it by converting data into stream of bits and bytes over the network in a raw format. Some media are designed for streaming text only. These protocols may interpret your binary data as control characters which they are not.

[Base64 Encoding](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/base64-encoding-and-decoding-example-in-java-8/) converts your binary data into 64 printable ASCII characters. Generally it is done for binary data in email messages and "basic" HTTP authentication. These 64 printable characters are:

- 26 uppercase letters [A-Z]
- 26 lowercase letters [a-z]
- 10 digits [0-9]
- 2 symbols

### Snapshot of Base64 Encoding Table

[image: Base64EncodingTable]